# How can I snap points to the grid in Vectornator X?

Tags: vector, snapping

Using Vectornator X on iPad, I can show the grid, and I can set the grid dimensions for example 20px x 20px.

When I draw a point, it does not snap the point to the grid.

How can I turn on snap to grid?

If it's impossible, is there another similar vector app which can do grid snapping?

Comment: FWIW, I'd suggest you also look into Affinity Designer on iPad - been using it a ton and it's doing the job for me. I used pixelmator and vectormator on my Mac a fair amount some years back, and liked them both well enough, but sadly I can't answer about snapping on the iPad version at the moment - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to enable or disable the Snap to Grid option in Vectornator.

1. When working inside your document press the gear wheel settings at the top left of the workspace
2. In the settings panel, below you’ll find the Snapping tab. Press to see the available options
3. Use the switch “Snap to Grid” to enable or disable

(I’m using the 3.1.11 (356) version)

[image: Snap to grid setting for Vectornator]